# Sorting listview(comparator) with ArrayAdapter, Android

Tags: android, listview, sorting, comparator

I'm writing program which will show user all application installed on his phone.

Each app has name, icon and rating. I have it all in class PInfo.

What I have in OnCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String temp = "";
        ArrayList<PInfo> list = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List<PackageInfo> packages = 

getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);


    for (int i = 0; i < packages.size(); ++i)
    {
        temp = packages.get(i).packageName;
        ApplicationInfo ai;
        try
        {
            ai = 

getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
                list.add(new PInfo(temp,
                    packages.get(i).applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString(),
                    getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(temp), 0));
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    final BuggedAdapter adapter = new BuggedAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Thus, I create and fill my listview with information.

Then I want to sort my list in alphabetical order or by rating.

With alphabetical order it's working perfectly, but with rating I have problem. 
It sort it by rating, but only a part of list. 
And only after I scroll up and down it will sort all list.

That's how I'm sorting it

```
public class RAT_DOWN implements Comparator<PInfo>
    {
        public int compare(PInfo left, PInfo right)
        {
            float change1 = left.rating;
            float change2 = right.rating;
            if (change1 < change2) return -1;
            if (change1 > change2) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And how I'm using it in my app

```
Collections.sort(list, new RAT_DOWN());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Why it works with alphabetical sort, but with rating sort there is this little problem?

Comment: have checked how much item available in sorting order according rating in list before calling notifyDataSetChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort rating

```
 public class RAT_DOWN implements Comparator<PInfo>
 {
            public int compare(PInfo left, PInfo right)
            {
                float change1 = left.rating;
                float change2 = right.rating;
                return change1.compareTo(change2);
            }
  }
```

Sort Alphabetic and rating:

```
public int compare(PInfo left, PInfo right)
{
    float change1 = left.rating;
    float change2 = right.rating;

    String leftName = left.name;
    String rightName = right.name;

    int nameComparator = leftName.compareTo(rightName);
    int comparable = valueWeekDay;

    if (comparable == 0) {
        comparable = change1compareTo(change2);
    }
    return comparable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting your custom class and try this code,

```
public class RAT_DOWN implements Comparator<PInfo>
{
    public int compare(PInfo left, PInfo right)
    {
        float change1 = left.rating;
        float change2 = right.rating;
        if (change1 != null && change2 != null) {
            return Float.compare(change1, change2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I hope solution for you have :)